# why overriding an ivar in @interface placed inside implementation is permitted but has this odd behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, overriding, ivar

I'm just curious about this question, I find this solution absolutely wrong, so I'm not using it, but since it happened to me erroneously (a typo that costed me hours of debugging) now I'm posting the question here to find an answer to why this all happened.

I have three classes:

the **SharedObject** class, which is a dumb class that does nothing...or well, *does stuff*:

```
// .h file
@interface SharedObject : NSObject

- (void) doStuff;

@end

// .m file
#import "SharedObject.h"

@implementation SharedObject

- (void) doStuff{

    NSLog(@"doin' stuff");
}

@end
```

the **Superclass** class which declares an ivar of **SharedObject** class, along with two methods, one just *should* (but doesn't) init the object, the other uses the object:

```
// .h file
#import "SharedObject.h"

@interface Superclass : NSObject{
    SharedObject *_sharedObj;
}

- (void) initSharedObject;
- (void) useSharedObject;

@end

// .m file
#import "Superclass.h"

@implementation Superclass

- (void) initSharedObject{
    ;;
}

- (void) useSharedObject{

    [_sharedObj doStuff];
}
@end
```

the **Subclass** class, subclass of **Superclass** (sorry for the naming mess!) which actually implements the `initSharedObject` method and inits **sharedObject**; This subclass however has an hidden category (here's the mess where no compile error is given) where the **SharedObject** ivar is overridden with the **exact same name**:

```
// .h file
#import "Superclass.h"

@interface Subclass : Superclass{

}
@end 

// .m file
#import "Subclass.h"

@interface Subclass (){
    //here's where the mess takes place
    SharedObject *_sharedObj;
}

@end

@implementation Subclass

- (void) initSharedObject{

    [super initSharedObject];

    //this class inits the shared object here.
    _sharedObj = [SharedObject new];

}
@end
```

Now, despite I'm aware of the fact that what's written up here is just **wrong**, I was asking myself why I'm getting this weird behaviour; If instantiate a **Subclass** and call `initSharedObject` and `useSharedObject`on it like this:

```
Subclass *test = [Subclass new];
[test initSharedObject];
[test useSharedObject];
```

nothing happens, and by nothing I mean **absolutely nothing**, no compile errors/warnings of course, but neither execution errors, the method call gets ignored and anything goes by; If I move the `useSharedObject` method implementation inside **Subclass** I have the correct log in console.
I'm wondering what happens exactly, at runtime, when I erroneously override that Ivar. Any guess I had feels smelly so I'd like to know if somebody has a precise and correct answer on how the compilation works in that scenario and why the log isn't called.

Comment: You didn't get warnings or errors because you didn't do anything explicitly wrong. The code did exactly what you told it to!

Comment: By the way, it's best to avoid declaring methods prefixed with `init` that aren't actual init methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of compiler diagnostic is a bug. The compiler should be able to see the duplicate ivars and complain. You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.

The behavior at runtime is correct. An instance of `Subclass` has two distinct ivars, even though they have the same name. `-[Subclass initSharedObject]` initializes the ivar declared in `Subclass`. Then `-[Superclass useSharedObject]` uses the ivar declared in `Superclass`. That ivar is `nil` so the call quietly does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The method doesn't get ignored. What is happening is you have two objects, I'll call them superSharedObject and sharedObject.

When you run initSharedObject, you are instantiating sharedObject. When you then call useSharedObject on `Subclass` (which doesn't implement useSharedObject) the `SuperClass`'s implementaiton of useSharedObject is run. That implementation uses superSharedObject, NOT sharedObject. In objective-c calling a method on an uninitialized(nil) object will not give you an error. It will simply do nothing or return nil if the method has output. This is by design.

Comment: So the fact that I get a compile error - precisely `Duplicate member _sharedObj` if I redeclare `SharedObject *_sharedObj` inside the interface file - that in this case is `Subclass.h` - and not in the hidden category inside the implementation file - again **Subclass.m** - happens because it is just the compiler telling me "this is wrong and I don't want you to do it" ? Shouldn't I be getting a warning for this?

Comment: One more reason to use properties instead of ivars!